# Use pdfminer coordinates for text highlighting on page JPEG files

Tags: python, html, pdf, highlighting

After using python pdfminer to get xml output about a pdf file's contents, I get a bbox coordinate set for each letter. I figured out that when it says

```
bbox="210.044,725.917,219.794,745.527"
bbox="a,b,c,d"
```

this describes a box where in pixel (for left-to-right languages)

```
a is the distance from the left page border to the left character border
b is the distance from the bottom page border to the bottom character border
c is the distance from the left page border to the right character border
d is the distance from the bottom page border to the top character border
```

Together with the extracted text information, this can be used to highlight defined text areas in HTML.

However, when I convert the source PDF to a JPEG file, these do not work any more as size has changed. Is there an easier way to do text highlighting on a graphic file than to recalculate the pixel values in relation to the generated page JPEG?

Comment: Isn't that easy then? First thing I thought after reading the intro: since the PDF coordinates are relative to its page size in *points*, you can directly transform them to identical coordinates in the JPEG's *pixel* units.